# Javascript change a button class onclick using "classList"

Tags: javascript, html

I want to change the appearance of two buttons when either one of them is clicked. But I cannot seem to do that.

I want the classes of the buttons to be changed every time a new button is clicked, but nothing is happening with this code. What could be the problem?

```js
function offbutton() {
    var offbtn = document.getElementById("btndisable3");
    var onbtn = document.getElementById("btnenable3");

    offbtn.classList.remove("btn btn-default");
    offbtn.classList.add("btn btn-danger active");
    onbtn.classList.remove("btn btn-success active");
  onbtn.classList.add("btn btn-default");
}

function onbutton() {
    var offbtn = document.getElementById("btndisable3");
    var onbtn = document.getElementById("btnenable3");

    onbtn.classList.remove("btn btn-default");
    onbtn.classList.add("btn btn-success active");
    offbtn.classList.remove("btn btn-danger active");
    offbtn.classList.add("btn btn-default");
}
```

```html
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">
    <?=$ name ?>
  </label>
  <div class="col-sm-10">
    <div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
      <label id="btndisable<?= $id ?>" class="btn <?php if($value == 0){ echo 'btn-danger active'; } else{ echo 'btn-default'; } ?>" onclick="offbutton();">
        <div class="col-sm-2">
          <input type="radio" name="options<?= $id ?>" id="disable<?= $id ?>" value="0" <?php if($value==0 ){ echo 'checked'; } ?>> O
        </div>
      </label>
      <label id="btnenable<?= $id ?>" class="btn <?php if($value == 1){ echo 'btn-success active'; } else{ echo 'btn-default'; } ?>" onclick="onbutton();">
        <div class="col-sm-2">
          <input type="radio" name="options<?= $id ?>" id="enable<?= $id ?>" value="1" <?php if($value=='1' ){ echo 'checked'; } ?>> I
        </div>
      </label>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you add this to a fiddle?

Comment: Do you mean switch button?

Comment: What is a switch button?

Comment: next time read the console `Error: { "message": "Uncaught InvalidCharacterError: Failed to execute 'remove' on 'DOMTokenList': The token provided ('btn btn-default') contains HTML space characters, which are not valid in tokens."... }`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to use comma `,` separator if you want to add/remove several classes so your code should be :

```
function offbutton() {
    var offbtn = document.getElementById("btndisable3");
    var onbtn = document.getElementById("btnenable3");

    offbtn.classList.remove("btn","btn-default");
    offbtn.classList.add("btn","btn-danger","active");
    onbtn.classList.remove("btn","btn-success","active");
    onbtn.classList.add("btn","btn-default");
}

function onbutton() {
    var offbtn = document.getElementById("btndisable3");
    var onbtn = document.getElementById("btnenable3");

    onbtn.classList.remove("btn","btn-default");
    onbtn.classList.add("btn","btn-success","active");
    offbtn.classList.remove("btn","btn-danger","active");
    offbtn.classList.add("btn","btn-default");
}
```

Hope this helps.